# Javascript Onclick Scroll and Highlight Example

Tags: javascript, onclick

Basically, I am trying to make a button that will have an onclick that when clicks the button will click and every click the clicks scrolls to another character or string. The character or string should highlight and scroll to the next. I cannot execute the code to work. I tried different tries. Please show me an example if mine is wrong.

I am a beginner at javascript. Also, I am using pure javascript.

```
var newclicks = document.getElementById('aclick');
newclicks.addEventListener('click', function() {
      for (var x = 0; 0 < document.length; x++) {
        if (str[0] == str2[0]) {
          var both = true;
          click.parentNode.style.backgroundColor = '#FF9900';
          var scrollLocation = str.location.toString();
          document.location = scrollLocation;
        }
      }
```

Comment: Why doing it yourself if someone already implemented it as a libarary (which is also free to use). Here is the basic demo: https://olivernn.github.io/moonwalkers/. library main page is https://lunrjs.com/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Checkout the sample snippet, I hope this is what you are looking into. please comment if you need any change or update;

```js
var newclicks = document.getElementById('aclick');
var str = document.getElementsByTagName('p')[0].innerText;
var length = str.split(/\s/).length;
var count = 0;
newclicks.addEventListener('click', function() {
  if(count < length){
   var temp = str.split(/\s/);
   temp[count] = '<span style= "background-color: yellow">'+temp[count]+'</span>';
   document.getElementsByTagName('p')[0].innerHTML = temp.join(' ');
    count++;
  }else{
    var temp = str.split(/\s/);
   temp[0] = '<span style= "background-color: yellow">'+temp[0]+'</span>';
   document.getElementsByTagName('p')[0].innerHTML = temp.join(' ');
    count = 1;
  }
})
```

```html
<p> This is a sample test code</p>
<button id="aclick"> Highlight</button>
```